# SSL renegotiation with full duplex socket communication

Tags: c, ssl, openssl

I have a very simple client-server with one blocking socket doing full-duplex communication. I've enabled SSL/TLS to the application. The model is that of a typical producer-consumer. The client produces the data, sends it to the server and the server processes them. The only catch is that, once in a while the server sends data back to the client which the client handles accordingly. Below is a very simple pseudo code of the application:

> ```
>   1 Client:
>   2 -------
>   3 while (true)
>   4 {
>   5         if (poll(pollin, timeout=0) || 0 < SSL_pending(ssl))
>   6         {
>   7                 SSL_read();
>   8                 // Handle WANT_READ or WANT_WRITE appropriately.
>   9                 // If no error, handle the received control message.
>  10         }
>  11         // produce data.
>  12         while (!poll(pollout))
>  13                 ; // Wait until the pipe is ready for a send().
>  14         SSL_write();
>  15         // Handle WANT_READ or WANT_WRITE appropriately.
>  16         if (time to renegotiate)
>  17                 SSL_renegotiate(ssl);
>  18 }
>  19
>  20 Server:
>  21 -------
>  22 while (true)
>  23 {
>  24         if (poll(pollin, timeout=1s) || 0 < SSL_pending(ssl))
>  25         {
>  26                 SSL_read();
>  27                 // Handle WANT_READ or WANT_WRITE appropriately.
>  28                 // If no error, consume data.
>  29         }
>  30         if (control message needs to be sent)
>  31         {
>  32                 while (!poll(pollout))
>  33                         ; // Wait until the pipe is ready for a send().
>  34                 SSL_write();
>  35                 // Handle WANT_READ or WANT_WRITE appropriately.
>  36         }
>  37 }
> ```

The trouble happens when, for testing purposes, I force SSL renegotiation (lines 16-17). The session starts nice and easy, but after a while, I get the following errors:

```
Client:
-------
error:140940F5:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:unexpected record

Server:
-------
error:140943F2:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert unexpected message
```

Turns out, around the same time that the client initiates a renegotiation (line 14), the server ends up sending application data to the client (line 34). The client as part of the renegotiation process receives this application data and bombs with a "unexpected record" error. Similarly, when the server does the subsequent receive (line 26), it ends up receiving a renegotiation data when it was expecting application data.

What am I doing wrong? How should I handle/test SSL renegotiations with a full-duplex channel. Note that, there are no threads involved. It's a simple single threaded model with reads/writes happening on either end of the socket.

**UPDATE** : To verify that there is nothing wrong with the application that I have written, I could even reproduce this quite comfortably with OpenSSL's s_client and s_server implementations. I started a s_server and once the s_client got connected to the server, I programmatically send a bunch of application data from the server to the client and a bunch of 'R' (renegotiation requests) from the client to the server. Eventually, they both fail in exactly the same manner as described above.

```
s_client:

RENEGOTIATING
4840:error:140940F5:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:unexpected record:s3_pkt.c:1258:

s_server:

Read BLOCK
ERROR
4838:error:140943F2:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert unexpected message:s3_pkt.c:1108:SSL alert number 10
4838:error:140940E5:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1185:
```

**UPDATE 2:**
Ok. As suggested by David, I reworked the test application to use non-blocking sockets and always do SSL_read and SSL_write first and do the select based on what they return and I still get the same errors during renegotiations (SSL_write ends up getting application data from the other side in the midst of renegotiation). The question is, at any point in time, if SSL_read returns WANT_READ, can I assume it is because there is nothing in the pipe and go ahead with SSL_write since I have something to write? If not, that's probably why I end up with errors. Either that, or I am doing the renegotiation all wrong. Note, if SSL_read returns WANT_WRITE, I always do a select and call SSL_read again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After spending time debugging my application with OpenSSL, I figured out the answer to the question I originally posted. I am sharing it here in case it helps others like me.

The question I had posted originally had to do with a clear error from OpenSSL indicating that it was receiving application data in the middle of a handshake. What I failed to understand was that OpenSSL gets confused when it receives application data in the middle of a handshake. It's fine to receive handshake data when receiving/sending application data but not the other way around (at least with OpenSSL). That's the thing that I failed to realize. This is also the reason most SSL-enabled applications run fine because most of them are half-duplex in nature (HTTPS for instance) which implicitly guarantees no application data asynchronously arriving at the time of handshake.

What this means is that if you are designing a custom client-server full-duplex protocol (which is the case I am in) and want to slap SSL onto it, it's the application's responsibility to initiate a renegotiation when neither end is sending any data. This is clearly documented in [Mozilla's NSS API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NSS/SSL_functions/sslfnc.html#1061582). Not to mention there is an [open ticket](http://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=2481&user=guest&pass=guest) in OpenSSL's bug repository regarding this issue. The moment I changed my application to initiate a handshake when there is nothing for the client/server to sayto one another, I no longer faced the above errors.

Also, I agree with David's comments about blocking sockets and I've read many of his arguments in the OpenSSL mailing list as well. But, the sad thing is that most legacy applications are built around poll and blocking sockets and they "Just Work Fine (TM)". The issue arises when dealing with SSL renegotiation. I still believe at least my application can deal with SSL renegotiation in the presence of blocking sockets since it is a very confined and custom protocol and we (as the application developer) can decide to do the renegotiation when the protocol is quiescent. If that doesn't work, I will go the non-blocking socket route.

Comment: This can happen with HTTPS too. You can stream requests (typically `GET`) and get their responses without blocking between each request/response pair. A re-negotiation in the middle of this would cause similar problems.

Comment: Saved me... had data exchange and the handshake... rather wait for the handshake to complete.

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to "look through" the SSL black box. This is a huge mistake.

```
     if (poll(pollin, timeout=0) || 0 < SSL_pending(ssl))
     {
             SSL_read();
```

You're making the assumption that in order for `SSL_read` to make forward progress, it needs to read data from the socket. This is an assumption that can be false. For example, if a renegotiation is in progress, the SSL engine may need to send data next, not read data.

```
     while (!poll(pollout))
             ; // Wait until the pipe is ready for a send().
     SSL_write();
```

How do you know the SSL engine wants to write data to the pipe? Did it give you a `WANT_WRITE` indication? If not, maybe it needs to read renegotiation data in order to send.

To use SSL in non-blocking mode, just attempt the operation you want to do. If you want to read decrypted data, call `SSL_read`. If you want to send encrypted data, call `SSL_write`. Only call `poll` if the SSL engine *tells you to*, with a `WANT_READ` or `WANT_WRITE` indication.

**Update**:: You have a "half of each" hybrid between blocking and non-blocking approaches. This cannot possibly work. The problem is simple: Until you call `SSL_read`, you don't know whether or not it needs to read from the socket. If you call `poll` first, you will block even if `SSL_read` does not need to read from the socket. If you call `SSL_read` first, it will block if it does need to read from the socket. `SSL_pending` won't help you. If `SSL_read` needs to *write* to the socket to make forward progress, `SSL_pending` will return zero, but calling `poll` will block forever.

You have two sane choices:

1. Blocking. Leave the sockets set blocking. Just call `SSL_read` when you want to read and `SSL_write` when you want to write. They *will* block. Blocking sockets can block, that's how they work.
2. Non-blocking. Set the sockets non-blocking. Just call `SSL_read` when you want to read and `SSL_write` when you want to write. They will not block. If you get a `WANT_READ` indication, poll in the read direction. If you get a `WANT_WRITE` indication, poll in the write direction. Note that it is perfectly normal for `SSL_read` to return `WANT_WRITE`, and then you poll in the write direction. Similarly, `SSL_write` can return `WANT_READ`, and then you poll in the read direction.

Your code would (mostly) work if the implementation of SSL_read was basically, "read some data then decrypt it" and SSL_write was "encrypt some data and send it". The problem is, these functions actually run a sophisticated state machine that reads and writes to the socket as needed and ultimately causes the effect of giving you decrypted data or encrypting your data and sending it.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, the socket I have is of blocking nature and with blocking sockets, poll() is one way to know you won't end up blocking on recv()/send(). If I don't use poll() and call SSL_read on a blocking socket, I am bound to block until the other side sends something. In that case, how to deal with SSL renegotiations?

Comment: @Karthik: You have to choose whether to use blocking sockets or non-blocking sockets and stick to that choice. If you want to use non-blocking sockets, set them non-blocking and follow my explanation. If you want to use blocking sockets, don't call `poll`. A "half of each" hybrid *will* *not* *work* for the reasons I explained -- polling on the *socket* does not tell you the readiness of the *SSL connection*.

Comment: There is no "half of each" hybrid. Both sides use blocking sockets and with blocking sockets, poll() is inevitable. Also, see my update. I could get the same behavior with OpenSSL's s_client and s_server both of which use blocking sockets and select()s before doing a SSL_read() or SSL_write.

Comment: David, first of all, why do you think the poll() I have above will block forever. I do have a timeout associated. In the client side, the timeout is 0 which means it is instantaneous. That's the only way I could ensure that I don't end up blocking forever when there is nothing really to read in which case my time is better spent sending some data (via SSL_write). This is especially useful when    the percentage of time the server sends anything to the client is a magnitude smaller than the percentage of time the client sends to the server. What you seem to indicate is that... contd.

Comment: ... with such a model, it's impossible to support SSL renegotiations unless non-blocking sockets are used.

Comment: @Karthik Oh, then you have a different bug. You're refusing to call `SSL_read` even if it can make forward progress just because no data has been received on the socket. What if `SSL_read` has to *write* to the socket to make forward progress?

Comment: *with such a model, it's impossible to support SSL renegotiations unless non-blocking sockets are used* -- Do you want to block or not? It is impossible to use blocking sockets and nevertheless not block. If you do not ever wish to block, you *must* use non-blocking sockets.

Comment: David, poll() and blocking sockets achieves pretty much what non-blocking I/O (especially in legacy applications like the ones I am dealing with) does but I now understand that model won't work with OpenSSL. The question, however, is that if SSL_read is skipped (as you mention above), why wouldn't the next SSL_write take care of doing the necessary I/O to finish renegotiation? In otherwords, as long as there is some I/O operation attempted, forward progress should be possible during renegotiations. Right? At least that's what I understood based on OpenSSL's doc about transparent renegotiation.

Comment: @Karthik: It really doesn't work with anything, except by luck. The `poll` function is a status-reporting function that tells you the status *now*, it doesn't come with any "future operation won't block" guarantee. You *must* set a socket non-blocking for that to happen. You're correct that `SSL_write` would trigger forward progress, but what if you have nothing to write? But that's far from the worst problem ...

Comment: Say this happens: There's a renegotiation in progress. You receive only renegotiation data, no application data. You get a `poll` hit for read, due to the renegotiation data, and call `SSL_read`. Oops, that blocks until *application* data has been read -- you can be waiting forever. The design is just 100% broken. And, again, it's broken for TCP and UDP too. It only works by luck. (And I can tell you stories of weird edge cases where it failed for TCP and UDP.)